# Using numpy 'module' object has no attribute 'array'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am just trying to convert a list to a 1D array like so:

```
import numpy as np

print np.array([2, 3, 4])
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numpy.py", line 11, in <module>
    test_run()
  File "numpy.py", line 8, in test_run
    print np.array([2, 3, 4])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array'
```

I tried reinstalling numpy because that seems to have worked for others, but this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You are most likely having a file called numpy.py in your working directory which shadows the real numpy module. Rename that file and remove its numpy.pyc file.

Comment: Yep, that was my problem!

Comment: It was a file called `platform.py` in my case!

Comment: Whlist following a tutorial I had called my test class numpy.py and this was being loaded instead...!

Comment: nice conflict same a filename are crazy system, rename work a thanks timgeb