# What's wrong in this code? Unknown attribute 'array' of type Module(<module 'numpy' from filename __init__.py'>

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I'm trying to create an array inside a function using @vectorize, I don't know why I keep receiving this error:

```
Unknown attribute 'array' of type Module( < module 'numpy' from 'filename.... /lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/ __ init __ .py'>)
```

Code:

```
from numba import vectorize, float32
import numpy as np

@vectorize([float32(float32[:,:], float32[:])], target='cuda')
def fitness(vrp_data, individual):
    # The first distance is from depot to the first node of the first route
    depot = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 40.0], dtype=np.float32)
    firstnode = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=np.float32)
    firstnode = vrp_data[vrp_data[:,0] == individual[0]][0] if 
individual[0] !=0 else depot

    x1 = depot[2]
    x2 = firstnode[2]
    y1 = depot[3]
    y2 = firstnode[3]

    dx = x1 - x2
    dy = y1 - y2
    totaldist = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

    return totaldist
```

The code works fine without the function decoration.

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of works and what doesn’t? See [ask] in the [help] for more information.

Comment: Thanks Ethan for the hint. I think my question is clear and the code is available, you can find answers if you just tried to run the code.

Comment: I do not have a python interpreter that I can use at the moment. But I know that error means that `Module.array` does not exist. Do you call `variable.array` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I jave modified the code to include the import lines I used. I used np.array after I imported numpy as np

Comment: `np.Array`, not `np.array`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using numpy 'module' object has no attribute 'array'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530726/using-numpy-module-object-has-no-attribute-array)

Comment: The auto completion shows array with lower case a. I used np.Array and got: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'Array'

Comment: `np.array` is a standard Numpy function for initializing an array from a sequence (such as a list). You're using it correctly (@EthanK the type is `np.ndarray`. `np.Array` doesn't exist).

Comment: @tel Oh. I don't use numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

`numpy.array` is not supported by Numba. Numba only supports a subset of the Numpy top-level functions (ie any function you call like `numpy.foo`). Here's an [identical issue from the Numba bug tracker](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1646).

## The "solution"

Here's the [list of Numpy functions that Numba actually supports](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html#other-functions). `numpy.zeros` is supported, so in an ideal world you could just change the lines in your code that use `np.array` to:

```
depot = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.float32)
depot[2:] = [30, 40]
firstnode = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.float32)
```

and it would work. However, when targeting `cuda` [all Numpy functions that allocate memory (including `np.zeros`) are disabled](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/cudapysupported.html#numpy-support). So you'll have to come up with a solution that doesn't involve any array allocation.

## Issues with use of `vectorize`

Also, it looks like `vectorize` is not the wrapper function you should be using. Instead, a function like the one you've written [requires the use of `guvectorize`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator). Here's the closest thing to your original code that I was able to get to work:

```
import math
from numba import guvectorize, float32
import numpy as np

@guvectorize([(float32[:,:], float32[:], float32[:])], '(m,n),(p)->()')
def fitness(vrp_data, individual, totaldist):
    # The first distance is from depot to the first node of the first route
    depot = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.float32)
    depot[2:] = [30, 40]
    firstnode = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.float32)
    firstnode = vrp_data[vrp_data[:,0] == individual[0]][0] if individual[0] !=0 else depot

    x1 = depot[2]
    x2 = firstnode[2]
    y1 = depot[3]
    y2 = firstnode[3]

    dx = x1 - x2
    dy = y1 - y2
    totaldist[0] = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
```

The third argument in the signature is actually the return value, so you call the function like:

```
vrp_data = np.arange(100, 100 + 4*4, dtype=np.float32).reshape(4,4)
individual = np.arange(100, 104, dtype=np.float32)

fitness(vrp_data, individual)
```

Output:

```
95.67131
```

## Better error message in latest Numba

You should probably upgrade your version of Numba. In the current version, your original code raises a somewhat more specific error message:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend). Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.array' or unsupported use of the function.
```

Comment: Wow! this is really beyond my expectations. Very neat, very detailed with example. Thank you very much.

* Can you please explain to me the meaning of:  '(m,n),(p)->()' in the decoration line?
* There is no 'target' argument for guvector ?

I think I will give up Anaconda since it does not upgrade numba over 0.39

Comment: Translated to plain english, `'(m,n),(p)->()'` as the second arg of `guvectorize` means: "This is a function that takes one array of shape `(m,n)` and one array of shape `(p)` and returns a scalar". `guvectorize` requires this second argument since the function being wrapped cannot have an explicit return value.

Comment: Thanks again @tel. One more question please, * There is no 'target='cuda'' argument for guvector ?

Comment: There is, but as I said in the answer when you have that flag set, all of the array creation functions will be disabled. You'll have to change the algorithm of your `fitness` function to deal with that. Either pass in pre-made versions of `depot` and `firstnode`, or make them plain lists.