# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'matrix' while using LogisticRegression.fit

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray

I am new to all this. Likely may have configuration problem.

```
import pandas as  pd

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy  as np
%matplotlib inline 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
import seaborn as sns 

from numpy import matrix
logisticreg = LogisticRegression()
logisticreg.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
```

Returns

```
File ...\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py:1303, in LogisticRegression.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1300 else:
   1301     n_threads = 1
-> 1303 fold_coefs_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose, prefer=prefer)(
   1304     path_func(
   1305         X,
   1306         y,
   1307         pos_class=class_,
   1308         Cs=[C_],
...
-> 1871     if isinstance(a, np.matrix):
   1872         return asarray(a).ravel(order=order)
   1873     else:


AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'matrix'
```

Running numpy version 1.26.2

Tried running example

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]])
# y = 1 * x_0 + 2 * x_1 + 3`
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
reg.score(X, y)
reg.coef_
reg.intercept_
reg.predict(np.array([[3, 5]]`))
```

Same error

Comment: [It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)

Comment: Do you have a file named [numpy.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530726/using-numpy-module-object-has-no-attribute-array), which Python is importing instead of the numpy library?

Comment: I have a numpy.py in ...\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays.

Comment: I have a numpy.py in ...\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays. </br> I have Anaconda3 installed but I couldn't get that to work at all. Note the machine I am used in sitting behind a firewall. Access the the world is extremely limited.</br>  Also what I have noticed is that I can see np.matrix. That appears to be valid in the jupyter notebook. Also I am using VSCode. @Ian Thompson

Comment: I was able to get the example code to run successfully. There was  an extra ` in the last line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what the problem was. The data object I passed in was not well formed. Correcting that seem to resolve the problem.